# CSS grid to ignore column if column doesn't exist

Tags: css-grid

If I have

```
grid-template-columns: 20vw 20vw 20vw 20vw;
```

But only 3 items, can I get the 3 items to center ignoring the 4th space? Or is that the wrong tool for this job and I should use another method like flexbox.

Comment: Flexbox would be a better tool here. Having set your grid to 4 columns you can't ignore one of them. You might experiment with `minmax` widths and a wrapper but that seems overly complex when flexbox will do this out of the box.